# Manipulate widget loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am embedding a widget into some html

```
   <div class="widget-hr-content">
    <div class="widget-hr-header"> 
    </div>
    <div class="widget-hr-facts">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script that calls the widget is this

```
 <script async src="https://somewebsitesscript"></script>
```

How would I use jquery to manipulate the anchor elements generated inside the div `class="widget-hr-facts"` , I know I can use `$('.widget-hr-facts').find('a').each` But where would I use it, I am not really understanding this. I tried to create a new script tag an add a defer attribute to it, didn't do anything for me.

```
<script async src="https://somewebsitesscript"></script>
<script async>
$('.widget-hr-facts').find('a').each(function(){
$(this).attr("href","redirectsomewherediffthanwidget");}); 
<script>
```

But the Jquery is failing out with `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: You would need to add another external script that also has `async` attribute after the one you mentioned here. By adding `async`, the browser loads the content while other processing continues. Because of this behavior you have not way of knowing when the script is ready to be used, except to add another async script tag, which will execute in the order you need.

Comment: I am wondering if this script is getting called before jquery is being loaded

Comment: Why async? Where/how is jquery loaded?

Comment: Good point @RuslanasBalčiūnas, don't forget to actually include jQuery in your page.

Comment: Its a .net application and jquery is getting loaded, its becomng a timing issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timing issue, the script was taking to long to load. I needed to update some of the rendered html with links redirecting the user. I did this using

> window.setTimeout(function()